# Passing instance property to static method in Async Tasks

Tags: c#, asynchronous, static

The code bellow:

```
namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var split = new SplitService();

            var tasks = new List<Task>();
            for (var nI = 0; nI < 10; nI++)
            {
                var fathers = new List<Father> { new Father { Id = Guid.NewGuid() } };

                var task = new Task (() => split.Split(fathers));
                tasks.Add(task);
            };

            foreach (var task in tasks)
            {
                task.Start();
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class SplitService
    {
        public IEnumerable<Father> Split(List<Father> fathers)
        {
            this.FatherProperties = fathers.GetFatherValues();

            this.RecalculateProperties(fathers);

            return fathers;
        }

        public List<FatherProperties> FatherProperties { get; private set; } = new List<FatherProperties>();

        public void RecalculateProperties(List<Father> fathers)
        {
            fathers.Update(this.FatherProperties);
        }
    }

    public static class FatherExtensions
    {
        public static List<FatherProperties> GetFatherValues(this List<Father> fathers)
        {
            return new List<FatherProperties>
            {
                new FatherProperties
                {
                    FatherId = fathers.FirstOrDefault().Id
                }
            };
        }

        public static void Update(this List<Father> fathers, List<FatherProperties> properties)
        {
            foreach (var father in fathers)
            {
                var match =
                    ( 
                     from value in properties
                     where value.FatherId == father.Id
                     select new
                     {
                         father.Id
                     }).SingleOrDefault();

                if (match == null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(match.Id); 
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class Father
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
    }

    public class FatherProperties
    {
        public Guid FatherId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Gives errors is more than one thread is running.
Can anyone help me with the reason why? 
Is this line:

```
fathers.Update(this.FatherProperties);
```

changes to this:

```
fathers.Update(father.GetFatherValues());
```

The code works.

Is this related to the access of the property? I can't figure out why.
I tried to read many websites but still can't find the reason of this error.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `Gives errors is more than one thread is running.` What line of code throws what exception?

Comment: There is no exception. The code should always have a match. If no match is thrown than I have an error.

Comment: There's no exception. Maybe the name is not the best.

Comment: What does `Gives errors is more than one thread is running.` mean?

Comment: If I produce a new object based in another with the same identifier. When I compare those two objects I should have same Ids on both objects. That is not what's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same instance of `SplitService` for all your tasks.
Inside you are modifying it's member `FatherProperties`.

Obviously, that's why you have this behavior.

Create a service for each task:

```
for (var nI = 0; nI < 10; nI++)
{
    var split = new SplitService(); // <-- a dedicated service for each

    var fathers = new List<Father> { new Father { Id = Guid.NewGuid() } };
    var task = new Task (() => split.Split(fathers));
    tasks.Add(task);
};
```

Comment: First of all thanks. That was the problem here. I think the code that I made as a sample of the real one does not represent entirely the problem.
I have DI making AddTransient of the splitService so it should be always a new instance.

Comment: Hi, You welcome. You should open a new question with all the details and a [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problematic DI code

Comment: Hi, I will produce a new sample with the same problem that I have and open a new question. Thanks for your help and time.

Answer (score 0):

First: Your excessive use of extension methods make the code very hard to read.
Second: You are pulling away the very collection you are using th compare. You use only ONE SplitService and its FatherProperties and you are changeing them in every call to split.Split(fathers). Since you are doing it multithreaded, you compare in one thread while another just puts a new fatherproperties collection in there. When using the GetFatherValues() again you are avoiding this behavior and therefore not getting an error.

Put the creation of the splitservice into the iteration.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var tasks = new List<Task>();
        for (var nI = 0; nI < 100; nI++)
        {
            var fathers = new List<Father> { new Father { Id = Guid.NewGuid() } };
            var split = new SplitService();
            var task = new Task(() => split.Split(fathers));
            tasks.Add(task);
        };

        foreach (var task in tasks)
        {
            task.Start();
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```